# Django-Angular, can return string but not objects or list

Tags: javascript, python, django, angularjs

Here is my simple code below. The template tag {{test}} will correctly display the returned "address" no problem. However, if I try to return an object or a list, I keep getting 500 Internal server error with the following

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) angular.js:8467
(anonymous function) angular.js:8467
sendReq angular.js:8263
$http.serverRequest angular.js:7995
wrappedCallback angular.js:11485
wrappedCallback angular.js:11485
(anonymous function) angular.js:11571
Scope.$eval angular.js:12595
Scope.$digest angular.js:12407
Scope.$apply angular.js:12699
(anonymous function) angular.js:18941
(anonymous function) angular.js:2822
forEach angular.js:325
eventHandler
```

**View.py**

```
class HomeView(JSONResponseMixin, TemplateView):
template_name='angular/base.html'

    @allow_remote_invocation
    def main_query(self, in_data):
        address = in_data.get('address')
        obj = Restaurant.objects.filter(pk=1)
        data = {'returns': address}
        return data
```

**Controller.js**

```
app.controller("GridFilter", function($scope, djangoRMI){
    $scope.addressValue = '';
    $scope.mainQuery = function() {
        var in_data = { address: $scope.addressValue };
        djangoRMI.main_query(in_data)
           .success(function(data) {
               $scope.test = data.returns;
           });
    };
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="GridFilter">
        <input type='text' ng-model='addressValue' />
        <button ng-click="mainQuery()">Submit</button>
         {{ test }}
    </div>
```

All I am trying to do is build a simple query where a person can enter in what to query for, js sends that data via remote method invocation to the main_query method, perform the query server side and return either an object or list. Not sure why I can return strings but not objects or lists. Using the JSONResponseMixin ensure the response is in json.

Whats going wrong? I've already tried many tiny tweaks to no success.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the case that you are experiencing a problem of json-serializability object.